# Django. TestCase is not running

Tags: python, django

Why if I run `python manage.py test appname` in my terminal is: Ran 0 tests in 0.000s OK

This is my tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
import appname.factories

class UserProfileTest(TestCase):
    def sample_data(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            user = appname.factories.UserProfileFactory.create()
```

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='', blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tel
```

My factories.py (factory boy):

```
from appname.models import *
import factory


class UserProfileFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = UserProfile

    street = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'Street' + n)
    tel = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'Tel' + n)
    password = 'abcdef'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your individual test functions should begin with the word 'test'.

You need to change the function `def sample_data(self):` to `def test_sample_data(self):`

The test runner will look for any classes in a file called `tests.py`, which sit in the root of your app, and which extend `unittest.TestCase`. Then it will run any functions within that class which begin with the word test (plus one or two other functions such as `setup()`)

I'm probably being obtuse, but I couldn't see anything in the [main django testing docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/) stating that functions must begin with the word test. Anyway, there's a reference to the requirement in [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial05/#running-tests) (official) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

`test.py` is wrong, it should be `tests.py`

Says [docs about writing tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests):

> For a given Django application, the test runner looks for unit tests in two places:
>
> - The models.py file. The test runner looks for any subclass of unittest.TestCase in this module.
> - **A file called tests.py** in the application directory – i.e., the directory that holds models.py. Again, the test runner looks for any subclass of unittest.TestCase in this module.

Comment: Sorry, I have tests.py in my project. That was not the cause of the error